# Django - Getting PIL Image save method to work with Amazon s3boto Storage

Tags: django, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library, boto

In order to resize images upon upload (using PIL), I'm overriding the save method for my Article model like so:

```
def save(self):
    super(Article, self).save()
    if self.image:
        size = (160, 160)
        image = Image.open(self.image)
        image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS) 
        image.save(self.image.path)
```

This works locally but in production I get an error:
NotImplementedError: This backend doesn't support absolute paths.

I tried replacing the image.save line with

```
image.save(self.image.url)
```

but then I get an IOError:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://my_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/article/article_images/2.jpg'

That is the correct location of the image though.  If I put that address in the browser, the image is there.  I tried a number of other things but so far, no luck.

Comment: Is this your first time running your site somewhere else besides your local machine?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should try and avoid saving to absolute paths;  there is a [File Storage API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/files/storage/) which abstracts these types of operations for you.

Looking at the [PIL Documentation](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm), it appears that the `save()` function supports passing a file-like object instead of a path.

I'm not in an environment where I can test this code, but I believe you would need to do something like this instead of your last line:

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage

fh = storage.open(self.image.name, "w")
format = 'png'  # You need to set the correct image format here
image.save(fh, format)
fh.close()
```

Comment: Tried it.  Got an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'.  It seems fh = None

Comment: I got it working by changing the first line.  I tried to edit your answer with the intent to accept it after the edit was approved but the edit was rejected.  Not sure why.  Here's what I added/changed to get it working: from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage                            

fh = storage.open(self.image.name, "w")

Comment: I m implementing the exact same thing, but its says there is an error in the _getencoder method. It takes 11 arguments but I m giving it 13.

Comment: I was creating corrupted images here until I changed `"w"` to `"wb"` (explicitly specifying that it's a binary file). Not sure what are the conditions for this change to be needed, though.

Answer (score 1):

For me default.storage.write() did not work, image.save() did not work, this one worked. See this code if anyone is still interested. I apologize for the indentation. My project was using Cloudinary and Django small project.

```
    from io import BytesIO
    from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
    from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage    

    def save(self, *args, **kargs):
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kargs)
    # After save, read the file
    image_read = storage.open(self.profile_image.name, "r")
    image = Image.open(image_read)
        if image.height > 200 or image.width > 200:
           size = 200, 200
        
          # Create a buffer to hold the bytes
           imageBuffer = BytesIO()

          # Resize  
           image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

          # Save the image as jpeg to the buffer
           image.save(imageBuffer, image.format)

          # Check whether it is resized
           image.show()

          # Save the modified image
           user = User.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
           user.profile_image.save(self.profile_image.name, ContentFile(imageBuffer.getvalue()))

           image_read = storage.open(user.profile_image.name, "r")
           image = Image.open(image_read)
           image.show()

        image_read.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are working with **cloud storages** for files in Django**

`NotImplementedError: This backend doesn't support absolute paths`

To fix it you need to replace `file.path` with `file.name`

For code in the the question: `image.save(self.image.path)` with `image.save(self.image.name)`

Here how it looks like in the console

```
>>> c = ContactImport.objects.last()

>>> c.json_file.name
'protected/json_files/data_SbLN1MpVGetUiN_uodPnd9yE2prgeTVTYKZ.json'

>>> c.json_file
<FieldFile: protected/json_files/data_SbLN1MpVGetUiN_uodPnd9yE2prgeTVTYKZ.json>

>>> c.json_file.url
'https://storage.googleapis.com/super-secret/media/api/protected/json_files/data_SbLN1MpVGetUiN_uodPnd9yE2prgeTVTYKZ.json?Expires=1631378947&GoogleAccessId=secret&Signature=ga7...'
```