# Django on heroku with s3 for media files. Have to edit model save method to switch between dev and prod?

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3

Hopefully someone can help with this. Thanks for having a look!

I am fairly new to django and programming in general so please bear with me. I am building a custom Profile app that has an avatar ImageField. I set it all up in development to resize and properly orient the image.  Went to push it to production on heroku and had to set up aws s3 to serve media.

I got an error with the save method of my avatar using Image.open(self.avatar.path).
The solution that ended up working was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680323/django-getting-pil-image-save-method-to-work-with-amazon-s3boto-storage/14681113). However, having changed the models save method i get the following error when trying to upload locally. There must be a better solution than having multiple save methods for production vs development. But I can't seem to find any info that addresses both cases. Thanks!

```
[22/Mar/2016 17:33:24] "GET /profiles/you/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6735
Internal Server Error: /profiles/you/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/venv_philabucks/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/venv_philabucks/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/venv_philabucks/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/venv_philabucks/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/vagrant/projects/philabucks/profiles/views.py", line 29, in post
    form.save()
  File "/vagrant/projects/philabucks/profiles/forms.py", line 30, in save
    user.save()
  File "/vagrant/projects/philabucks/profiles/models.py", line 108, in save
    image.save(fh, format)
  File "/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/venv_philabucks/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1675, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/venv_philabucks/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 690, in _save
    fp.write(_MAGIC)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
[22/Mar/2016 17:33:45] "POST /profiles/you/ HTTP/1.1" 500 92102
```

Here are the relevant parts of my Profile Model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
from PIL import Image, ExifTags
from PIL.ImageOps import fit
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage

avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)

def save(self, **kwargs):
    super(Profile, self).save()
    if self.avatar:
        image = Image.open(storage.open(self.avatar.name))
        try:
            for orientation in ExifTags.TAGS.keys():
                if ExifTags.TAGS[orientation]=='Orientation':
                    break
            exif=dict(image._getexif().items())
            if exif[orientation] == 3:
                image=image.rotate(180, expand=True)
            elif exif[orientation] == 6:
                image=image.rotate(270, expand=True)
            elif exif[orientation] == 8:
                image=image.rotate(90, expand=True)
        except (AttributeError, KeyError, IndexError):
            # cases: image don't have getexif
            pass

        image = fit(image, (200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        fh = storage.open(self.avatar.name, "w")
        format = 'png'  # You need to set the correct image format here
        image.save(fh, format)
        fh.close()
```

Here's the s3 settings from settings/production.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ['storages',]

AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
MEDIA_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/your-folder/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage"


AWS_AUTO_CREATE_BUCKET = True

AWS_HEADERS = {
    "Cache-Control": "public, max-age=86400",
}

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False

AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = True

AWS_REDUCED_REDUNDANCY = False

AWS_IS_GZIPPED = False
```

Here's the media storage from settings/local.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: how did you add s3 storage to your app and how heroku support?

Comment: I added the s3 settings to my initial question. I set all the config variables using heroku config:set

Comment: first control your settings, mine look quite different: [compare](https://gist.github.com/niklasp/2fff10d48839d15e6ba1)

Comment: Just to be clear, my production settings seem to be working fine. Its when I go back to development and try to store media in /media in my project that I get the error. It seems like changing from image = image.open(self.avatar.path) to image = Image.open(storage.open(self.avatar.name)) makes it work in production but kills it in development.

Comment: I added the your code into mine omitting STATIC_URL as I'm not using s3 for static at this point. I still get the exact same error when trying to run locally.  I edited my original post to reflect the changes and also added in my local media settings.  Thanks for helping with this!

Comment: Basic question - is your dev environment is running the same Python version as Heroku? Note that your logs show 3.4; Heroku defaults to 2.7.11 (as of Feb 2016, per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes). The error "must be str, not bytes" looks like a 2 to 3 migration error. Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512811/builtins-typeerror-must-be-str-not-bytes, I would try opening the file in binary mode (flag `wb`.

Comment: Yeah I have a runtime.txt file with the appropriate version set. Again everything runs fine in heroku I get that error when running locally after changing the save method to work on heroku and s3 by adding in django storages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by changing this line:

```
    fh = storage.open(self.avatar.name, "w")
```

to this

```
    fh = storage.open(self.avatar.name, "wb")
```

after finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512811/builtins-typeerror-must-be-str-not-bytes) wonderfully helpful answer. I'm still not sure why it worked in heroku but not locally but the "wb" opens it in binary and makes it work in both cases.